# Is it possible to subscript into a uint64_t pointer in C?

Tags: c, pointers, indexing, casting

I'm a C beginner. Having trouble understanding whats happening with this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main(void)
{
    uint64_t num = 99999;
    uint64_t *num_ptr = &num;

    uint8_t first_byte = ((uint8_t *)num_ptr)[0];

    printf("%hhu", first_byte);

    return 0;
}
```

This prints `159`.

I'm looking at `uint8_t first_byte = ((uint8_t *)num_ptr)[0];`

I'm trying to understand it this way: the uint64_t pointer `num_ptr` is first cast as a uint8_t pointer, then we index into it with the square brackets to get the first byte. Is this a correct explanation? If so is it possible to index into pointers to get their partial contents without dereferencing?

Comment: First of all `99999` -> `0x0102030405060708`. Then your output will be easier to understand (output will be `8`). Your explanation sounds correct. But I didn't understand this question : _"If so is it possible to index into pointers to get their partial contents without dereferencing?"_, especially the _without dereferencing_ part is odd.

Comment: `99999` is `0x1869f`, and on little-endian machines the first byte is the `0x9f` which is 159 decimal. The code is casting the `num_ptr` to a byte pointer (`uint8_t *`) and then it dereferences that pointer using array syntax. In C, `array[i]` is the same as `*(array + i)` by definition. So `ptr[0]` is the same as `*(ptr + 0)` which is the same as `*ptr`.

Comment: maybe [this will help?](https://godbolt.org/z/vKq1sG7en). When you print it one byte at a time (my preference is in hex), you can see how the `uint8_t` pointer can point to each byte of the `uint64_t` number. You can see with `0x9f` being first, godbolt is executing on a little endian machine. In terms of your last question, not sure I follow either.. where ever the pointer points, you have to dereference to read what it points at.

Comment: If I was writing that code, I would have declared `num_ptr` as a byte pointer, i.e. `uint8_t *num_ptr = (uint8_t *)&num;`. Then you could access the bytes without the cast, e.g. `uint8_t first_byte = num_ptr[0];` `uint8_t second_byte = num_ptr[1];` etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `99999` = `0x1869F` or if you will as a 64 bit number `0000 0000 0001 869F`
- Intel/PC computers use little endian. [What is CPU endianness?](https://software.codidact.com/posts/280640)
- Therefore your 64 bit number is stored in memory as `9F86 0100 0000 0000`.
- C allows us to inspect a larger data type byte by byte through a pointer to a character type. `uint8_t` is a character type on all non-exotic systems.
- `((uint8_t *)num_ptr)[0];` Converts the 64 bit pointer to a 8 bit (character) pointer and then uses the `[]` operator to de-reference that pointer.
- We get the first byte `0x9F` = 159 dec.
- `%hhu` is used to print `unsigned char`. The most correct conversion specifier to use for `uint8_t` would otherwise be `"%" PRIU8` from `inttypes.h`

Answer (score 2):

Consider a work-alike program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

typedef union td_USixtyFour
{
    uint64_t whole;
    uint8_t  parts[sizeof(uint64_t)];
} USixtyFour;


int main( int argc, char **argv )
{
    USixtyFour number;
    number.whole = 99999;

    printf( "number.parts[0] is %u / 0x%02x\n", number.parts[0], number.parts[0] );

    return 0;
}
```

Which outputs:

```
number.parts[0] is 159 / 0x9f
```

Here with a [C union](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_unions.htm), it's simulating what was done in the OP's code.  The `.parts` covers the same memory as the `.whole`.  So in essence the `parts` is giving access to the content of the `uint64_t`'s bytes-in-memory without any sort of pointer dereference.

This sort of operation will have issues with portability due to  [endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness), and should generally be avoided.  Of course one could mitigate this by packing into network-byte-order with functions like `htonl()`, so a known order is preserved.

Comment: `_U64_t` and `U64_t` are both reserved identifiers.  `_U64_t` is reserved per [C11 7.1.3, paragraph 1](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.1.3p1) because of the leading underscore and then a capital letter, and it's reserved under [POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_02_02) for the `_t` ending.  `U64_t` is reserved under POSIX.

Answer (score 0):

1. What you do is a "pointer punning". Generally it is a dangerous operation, might invoke Undefined Behavior and violate strict aliasing rule. But when you access other data as `char`s it is OK.

```
int main(void)
{
    uint64_t num = 99999;
    uint64_t *num_ptr = &num;

    printf("%016"PRIx64"\n", num);

    for(size_t index = 0; index < sizeof(num); index++)
    {
        printf("Index = %2zu, value= %02hhx\n", index, ((unsigned char *)num_ptr)[index]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The safest method is to use `memcpy`

```
int main(void)
{
    uint64_t num = 99999;
    uint64_t *num_ptr = &num;

    unsigned char arr[sizeof(num)];

    printf("%016"PRIx64"\n", num);

    memcpy(arr, &num, sizeof(num));

    for(size_t index = 0; index < sizeof(num); index++)
    {
        printf("Index = %2zu, value= %02hhx\n", index, arr[index]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```